# Identificaton of CRC algorithm

Tags: reverse-engineering, crc

I want to fix some CRC problems (I hope this is CRC). Through reverse engineering of C++ program I managed to find function which calculates this CRC.

```
result = initialPolynomialValue;    
for ( i = testedMemorySize; i; --i )
{
  MemValToTest = *ptrMemToTest;
  unsigned int v7 = (result >> 4) ^ 4225h * ((MemValToTest ^ result) & 0xF);
  result = (v7 >> 4) ^ 4225h * ((v7 ^ (MemValToTest >> 4)) & 0xF)
  ptrMemToTest = (ptrMemToTest + 1);
}
```

Could you identify this CRC algorithm for me? What group it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *looks* like it's just CRC-16 with a custom polynom (x<sup>16</sup> + x<sup>14</sup> + x<sup>9</sup> + x<sup>5</sup> + x<sup>2</sup> + 1).